# how to post json format data to server

Tags: android, json

How to post JSON data to .net server?

**can i use:**

```
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Code", Code));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Subject", Subject));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

or any other format to send json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution after referring many sources...

```
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            jsonObject.put("Code", Code);
            jsonObject.put("Subject", Subject);

            stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
            stringEntity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);


            httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpPost);  

                 return null;

           }



            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
              //to see the response

            httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
            Response=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            System.out.println("Response "+Response);

            int Response_Code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            System.out.println("Response_Code "+Response_Code);


            }
```

Thanks for your response, also helped me find this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `JSON` Object and Put data into that object and pass it to the server..

use,

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("UserName", "test2");
json.put("FullName", "1234567");
```

to put data into json object...

use
`json.toString();` to send the data and
`request.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");`
to mark the json format...

Refer these links for more:

1. [Send and Receive Json android-php](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php)
2. [Sending json from Android](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/727446/Sending-json-object-to-ASP-net-Csharp-from-Android)

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more parameter to the URL named json(or any name you want), and use the json string as value and then get the json in your php.

**example:**

```
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Code", Code));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Subject", Subject));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Json", my_jsons_tring));
```

Comment: @Sravani yes in string